# GKAchievementDescription and unlocked list

Tags: objective-c, ios, gamekit

Is there a way to get all the GKAchievementDescription list with achievement status (locked, unlocked or percent) ?

I just logged that

```
[GKAchievementDescription loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *descriptions, NSError *error) 
 {
     NSLog(@"description %@",descriptions);
 }];
```

but I can't figure out how to know each state of each achievement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

Do this:

```
[GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error) { 

    [GKAchievementDescription loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *descriptions, NSError *error) 
     {
       for(GKAchievementDescription *myDescription in descriptions) {

for(GKAchievement *myAch in achievements) {

if ([myDescription.identifier isEqualToString:[myAch.identifier])
// the achievement is earned earned add it to array - do things - break;
  }
}

}]; }];
```

The idea is when you get achievements with `loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler` method, it only returns the submitted achievements. From there you can filter the required descriptions.